# New JavaScript prototype changes constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

When you create an object with a constructor it has a `constructor` property pointing to the constructor function:

```
var Foo = function(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
var myFoo = new Foo(123);
myFoo.constructor === Foo; // true
```

After creating this object I can change `Foo.prototype` ...

```
Foo.prototype.x = 'y';
```

... or reassign a new prototype object:

```
Foo.prototype = {
    num: 99
};
myFoo.constructor === Foo; // still true
```

But if I create a new Foo object **after** assigning a new object to `Foo.prototype` its constructor suddenly points to `Object`:

```
var myBar = new Foo(321);
myBar.constructor === Foo; // false
myBar.constructor === Object; // wtf?!
```

Adding new properties to the prototype doesn't produce this effect, you have to do the assignment `Foo.prototype = {...}`.

I have no idea why creating a new prototype would affect the constructor property. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, all with the same result. Can anybody help me understand this?

Comment: Use `console.dir(myFoo)` and `console.dir(myBar)` and you will see. Note: Assigning a new value to `Func.prototype` does **not** affect existing instances of that constructor. Just in the same as `var foo = 10; var bar = foo; bar = 5;` won't set `foo` to `5`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with console.dir, that makes things indeed clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` property of any object is inherited from that object's prototype.

The default `prototype` object created with any function contains a `constructor` property that refers to that function, as detailed in the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2).

Your new `prototype` object doesn't have that `constructor` property, and instead has its own `constructor` property inherited from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: that's why in "use strict", you can delete Function.prototype.constructor for security, and they can't get it back.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up:

- `myFoo.constructor` is in fact `myFoo.__proto__.constructor`.
- Creating a new prototype doesn't affect existing objects. In the example above, `myFoo.x` has the value `"y"` but `myFoo.num` is `undefined`.
- Newly created objects use that new prototype, of course, which has no property `constructor`. Therefore they inherit it. In the example above, `myBar.constructor` is in fact `myBar.__proto__.__proto__.constructor` which points to `Object`.

If you assign a new prototype from an object literal you simply can set a constructor property:

```
var Foo = function(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
};
var myFoo = new Foo(123);

Foo.prototype = {
    num: 99,
    constructor: Foo
};
var myBar = new Foo(99);

myBar.constructor === myFoo.constructor; // true
```

Or, more precisely:

```
Foo.prototype = {
    num: 99
};
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "constructor", {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Foo
});
```